# debian Read-only file system error

Tags: debian, hard-drive, hardware, io, read-only

I logged on to my debian box and tried running some commands and I was presented with the following message.

```
sudo: Can't open /var/lib/sudo/username/0: Read-only file system
```

After doing some digging I discovered that the fstab had an option on the root partition that would remount it as read only: `errors=remount-ro`

I suspect it remount the error in case of a file system consistency issue.

Now I have come across a tool fsck and some say it may resolve the issue using the command

```
sudo  fsck -t ext3 /dev/sda[n]
```

according to [this article](http://peterwang.org/blog/2011/04/24/linux-file-system-goes-read-only/).

I suspect i could remount it and change the read only restriction however if the debian changed it to avoid further damage or loss of information i think it wouldn't be a good idea.

However there is no guarantee it would work for mine and it may even cause more issues.

Does anyone have any advice on what steps to take?

**EDIT**

Below is the first section of the FSTAB

UUID=e2887ae1-xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxx /               ext3    errors=remount-ro 0       1

Answer (score 1):

You should boot a different Linux installation (thus you should always have a small service Linux on the same disk), from CD/DVD/USB if there is no other one on the disk and do the fsck from there.

Comment: This is my dilemma, it is a remote machine i do not have physical access to it. 
However I do have the 3 debian iso mounted on the machine but i'm not sure I can boot it from this.

Comment: @KyaleMwendwa If you find the kernel file and its initrd on that iso then you can boot from there via `kexec`.